# real part of a division result in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need the real part of a division result in pl sql.
I have searched  whole the google although i could not find it. It seems Oracle round the result to the nearest real number

```
numb:=(numb/10);
dbms_output.put_line(numb);
```

Comment: `I have searched whole the google`. Well that's impressive. Give us a little more information on what you are actually looking for? At least, what is the data type of the `numb` variable, what it's initial value(now it seems to be `null` and not only you won't see a "real part of the division" (reminder?) you won't be able to see anything at all). What's your desired output. [Ho do I ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you mean by "real part"? Are you talking about [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)?

Comment: Perhaps a reproducible test case would help explain the issue you are having.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov if you do not want to help you can be quiet . tnx man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a block of code that calculates integer and fractional part of the number:

```
DECLARE
    numb NUMBER := 987;
    n1   NUMBER;
    n2   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    n1 := TRUNC(numb / 10);
    n2 := MOD(numb, 10);

    dbms_output.put_line('n1=' || n1); -- n1=98
    dbms_output.put_line('n2=' || n2); -- n2=7
END;
```